# Remnants from package installation

Tags: package-management

I'm on Yosemite 10.10.1

I was trying to install the Tor browser, but instead I mistakenly installed some general Tor proxy or something, which didn't come in the form of a normal application.

Basically I first installed MacPorts and then I `sudo port install tor` which didn't give me the Tor browser, but some other Tor thing (I think it's something that allows you to use Tor proxy with any application, but I don't need that.)

So anyway, that command installed a bunch of components that I don't want or need on my system. How can I purge all these components from my system?

Here is the output from `sudo port install tor` (I have ran `sudo port uninstall tor` now, but I'm thinking some of the other stuff is still left behind.)

```
Fiksdals-iMac:~ Fiksdal$ sudo port install tor
Error: 
Error: No Xcode installation was found.
Error: Please install Xcode and/or run xcode-select to specify its location.
Error: 
Warning: xcodebuild exists but failed to execute
Warning: Xcode does not appear to be installed; most ports will likely fail to build.
--->  Computing dependencies for tor
--->  Fetching archive for tor
Warning: Your DNS servers incorrectly claim to know the address of nonexistent hosts. This may cause checksum mismatches for some ports. See this page for more information: <https://trac.macports.org/wiki/MisbehavingServers>
--->  Attempting to fetch tor-0.2.6.9_1.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/tor
--->  Attempting to fetch tor-0.2.6.9_1.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/tor
--->  Installing tor @0.2.6.9_1
--->  Activating tor @0.2.6.9_1
--->  Cleaning tor
--->  Updating database of binaries
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.
Fiksdals-iMac:~ Fiksdal$
```

Edit: I opened `MacPorts.txt` and found the following. Was this added during my installation of Tor?

libevent @2.0.22_1 (active)
  openssl @1.0.2d_0 (active)
  zlib @1.2.8_0 (active)

Comment: What makes you think that some files are left behind?

Comment: Are you saying there probably aren't any? I mean, the installer seemed to install more than one thing, and when I uninstalled it was only Tor.

Comment: Your log output only shows `tor`.

Comment: Actually, this is from when I ran the same command again later, the first time I ran it there was a bunch of stuff happening.. This is kind of silly really.

Comment: I added some more info to the question, this is what I am talking about.

Comment: Please read the MacPorts Guide- `port deps tor` . You need to fix the problem with XCode before worrying about crud left after an uninstall.